# MYSQL: query that shows a checklist of all user roles

Tags: mysql

I have a list of users that belong to a certain roles.

I have three MySQL tables: *users*, *roles*, and *userRoles* that relates both tables.

For an "edit user" form I need to show a list of all available roles in the *roles* table, and from all of them, to show as checked the ones that the user belongs to.

I've got a problem into my query, because If I try to output the list grouping by role name (to avoid duplicates), all users won't appear in the list. And If I avoid the grouping, the roles list has duplicates.
I've tried with DISTINCT, and the output is still duplicated.

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT  roles.roleID, roles.nombreRol AS rolusuario,
                                    usuarios.userID AS usuarioid, 
                                    rolesUsuarios.userID, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
                            FROM roles LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
                            ON roles.nombreRol = rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
                            LEFT JOIN usuarios
                            ON rolesUsuarios.userID = usuarios.userID


SELECT  roles.roleID, roles.nombreRol AS rolusuario,
                                    usuarios.userID AS usuarioid, 
                                    rolesUsuarios.userID, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
                            FROM roles LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
                            ON roles.nombreRol = rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
                            LEFT JOIN usuarios
                            ON rolesUsuarios.userID = usuarios.userID
                            GROUP BY roles.nombreRol
```

I've also tried changing the order of the JOINS as a test:

```
                            SELECT roles.roleID, roles.nombreRol,
                                    usuarios.userID, 
                                    rolesUsuarios.userID, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
                            FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
                            ON usuarios.userID = rolesUsuarios.userID
                            LEFT JOIN roles
                            ON roles.nombreRol = rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
GROUP BY roles.nombreRol
```

But that way, I only get as a result the list of roles where there's a user in it.

These are my three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
    roleID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userEmail char(50) null,
...
);

CREATE TABLE rolesUsuarios (
    rolesUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
);
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is 'never use comma join syntax', and definitely never user it in combination with regular join syntax

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just select from roles, left join to userRoles, filtered on userRoles.userID, and not receive any duplicates or need to use distinct or grouping to try and eliminate them.

Where any result from userRoles has a value, the role is selected and should be checked, where it is null, it is unchecked.

Something like:

```
select r.roleID, case when ru.userID is null then 'Unchecked' else 'Checked' end as checkbox
from roles r
left join rolesUsuarios ru
on r.nombreRol = ru.nombreRol
and ru.userID = ?
```

Replace ? with your bind parameter for the current user ID you are filtering for.

If the data for your nombreRol columns is sound, it should work as-is without any other aggregates.

To show results for other queries (e.g. all users, for a specific role), I would go with separate SQL instead of making one query perform both operations (if that was your aim).

Answer (score 1):

Table modification suggested:

1. Table rolesUsuarios should have roleId as another column and set it to foreign key to roldeId in the roles column.
2. UserId column in rolesUsuarios should be foreign key and point to UserId in usuarios table.
3. There is no need for rolesUsuariosID column in rolesUsuarios table. You can combine userId and RoleId together to make a primary key.
4. nombreRol is already present in Roles table so not required in rolesUsuarios table.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT
    roles.roleID
    ,roles.nombreRol AS rolusuario
    ,rolesUsuarios.userID
FROM roles 
LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
ON roles.nombreRol = rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
```

Assumption:rolesUsuarios.nombreRol has the same values as the one present in roles.nombreRol column in Roles table.
If you modify your table structure then the above query would change accordingly keeping columns to be joined in consideration.